# Is there a way to get the * command to ignore certain entries?

Tags: regex, makefile

I have a lot of a files in one of my folders that I need *.c to compile them in my Makefile,  but I want to exclude one of them for now. Is there anyway to still use *.c but ignore a specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SOURCES := $(filter-out foo.c,$(wildcard *.c))
```